# PostgreSQL - change precision of numeric?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2, alter-table

I tried to change precision like this:

```
ALTER Table account_invoice ALTER amount_total SET NUMERIC(5);
```

But I get syntax error, so I'm clearly doing something wrong. What is the right syntax to change precision of numeric in PostgreSQL?

Comment: `alter table account_invoice alter column amount_type type decimal(5,0);` ?  or like this `ALTER TABLE acc_inv MODIFY amount_total NUMERIC(5,0); ?`

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi Post it as answer

Comment: i was taking a guess ! @ClodoaldoNeto i posted as answer !

Comment: The right syntax is documented: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this:

```
ALTER Table account_invoice ALTER COLUMN amount_total TYPE DECIMAL(10,5);
```

`DECIMAL(X, Y)` -> X represents full length and Y represents precision of the number.

Comment: Just terms are a bit confusing in PostgreSQL here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html. As precision here is called full length of numbers.
Also why DECIMAL not NUMERIC?

Comment: they are not different in postgresql you could use numeric as well. it maybe better indeed.

Comment: No need to change the data type to DECIMAL. This can also be done with data type NUMERIC as answered by Maike Mota.

Comment: Confirming Andrius' comment, I believe the X,Y in this answer are switched. X is precision and Y is Scale - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-numeric.html#id-1.5.7.9.7.4 (link to exact paragraph)

Answer (score 16):

You can use this:

```
ALTER Table account_invoice ALTER amount_total SET DATA TYPE NUMERIC(5,Y);
```

where Y is your required level of precision.

Comment: FYI: 5 is  precision and Y is scale

Comment: I can see the confusion thats my comment about the Y's value can cause, when I said **"precision"** I wanted to mean the **amount of decimal places**, the POSTGRE documentation refers to _precision_ as the total number of digits that a number could contains and the _scale_ as the total of digits reserved to be fractional (AKA. decimal places). Thanks for bring my attention to this!

Comment: **NUMERIC(precision, scale).**

The _scale_ of a numeric is the count of decimal digits in the fractional part, to the right of the decimal point. The _precision_ of a numeric is the total count of significant digits in the whole number, that is, the number of digits to both sides of the decimal point. So the number 23.5141 has a precision of 6 and a scale of 4. Integers can be considered to have a scale of zero. [source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-numeric.html)

Answer (score 7):

You need to ue the `TYPE` keyword after the column name, not SET

```
ALTER Table account_invoice ALTER amount_total TYPE NUMERIC(5);
```

See the docs: [ALTER TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-altertable.html)

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c63ff)**